# proof of roots of characteristic polynomial are eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

How do I prove the 2 directions of this statement?

[image]

Comment: How do you define eigenvalue?  Usually (i) is its definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A root $r$ of characteristic polynomial provides equation $det(M - r Id)=0$ so $M-r Id$ hasn't a full rank and there exist a nontrivial vector $\tilde{v}$ with $0 =(M-rId)\tilde{v}= M\tilde{v}-r\tilde{v}$ so $M\tilde{v}= r\tilde{v}$ and $r$ is by definition an eigenvalue. Walking backwards alongside my arguments provides the proof in other direction.