# How to prove that this matrix is diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I am trying assignment questions of Linear algebra and couldn't solve this particular question regarding diagonalizabilty.

> Let $n \times n$ complex matrix $A$ satisfies $A^k = I$ the $n \times n $ identity matrix, where $k$ is a positive integer $>1$ and let $1$ not be an eigenvalue of $A$. Then how to prove that A is necessarity Diagonalizable?

As $A^k=I$  and 1 is not an eigenvalue so $(A-I ) (A^{k-1}+...+ I)=0$ implies that $(A^{k-1}+...+ I)=0$ but I am unable to move foreward .

Can you please help?

Comment: It is important to point out that AB=0 does not imply A=0 or B=0. In this case however, since I is not an eigenvalue we know that A-I is invertible, so that multiplying by the inverse, yeah.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have assumed less. The condition "1 is not an eigenvalue of $A$" is unnecessary.

Recall that a complex matrix $A$ is diagonizable if and only if its minimal polynomial has no multiple roots. If $A^k = I$, then the minimal polynomial of $A$, which we denote by $f(x)$, necessarily divides $x^k - 1$. We conclude that $f(x)$ cannot have multiple roots since $x^k - 1$ has $k$ distinct roots in $\mathbb{C}$. Hence $A$ is diagonizable.

Alternatively, we may use Jordan Canonical Form to see the diagonizability. Suppose on the contrary $A$ is not diagonalizable, then there must exist some nontrivial Jordan block $B$ of the Jordan Canonical Form in the following form:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 1       & 0       & \cdots  & 0 \\
0       & \lambda & 1       & \cdots  & 0 \\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots& \ddots  & \vdots \\
0       & 0       & 0        & \lambda & 1       \\
0       & 0       & 0       & 0       & \lambda \end{pmatrix}$$
which satisfies $B^k = I$. This is impossible by calculating, for example, the $(1,2)$-entry of $B^k$, since $\lambda \neq 0$.

Comment: The assumption 1 is not an eigenvalue is strange, your argument indicates that 1 is an eigenvalue.

Comment: 1 may be and may not be an eigenvalue. Anyway, any eigenvalue is a root of x^k-1 for sure.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2567988/proof-of-roots-of-characteristic-polynomial-are-eigenvalues/2568001 , and 1 is a root of x^k-1.

Comment: Consider $1 \times 1$ matrix $A = (-1)$. Then $A^2 = I$. But $-1$ is the ONLY eigenvalue of $(-1)$.

Comment: That was a simple, but illuminating example. Thank you for the patience. My logic was wrong, because I was thinking that $k\leq n$, in this case would 1 be a eigenvalue?

Comment: No, because we can still use $A = \mathrm{diag}\{-1, -1, \dots, -1\}$ as a counterexample, in which case $k =2$ but $n$ can be arbitrarily large. In fact, I can't see any natural way of requiring that $1$ be an eigenvalue, since $1$ is not very different from the other $n-1$ roots of $x^n = 1$, also candidates of the eigenvalues,  in this sense.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=SJS^{-1}$ be the Jordan normal form then $A^{k}=(SJS^{-1})^k=(SJ^{k}S^{-1})=I$. Then multiplying by $S^{-1}$ on the left and $S$ on the right yields $J^k=I$. If $J$ had a Jordan block $J_i$ of size $n>1$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_{i}$, then $J_i^k$ would have super diagonal entries $(2\lambda_{i})^{(k-1)}\neq 0$.

Comment: "If $J$ had a non-trivial Jordan block, then no power of that block would be identity" - could you add some details here? Why is this true?

Comment: Take powers of the matrix of \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: So our conclusion then is $J=I$ right?

Comment: Not quite, the conclusion by contradiction is that all Jordan blocks have size 1, so our Jordan normal form is diagonal, with diagonal entries the eigenvalues.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is a Theorem which says that If any square Matrix A is Diagonizable then any positive power of A    ie A^k , k belong to Z+. A^k is also Diagonizable

BUT THE CONVERSE part is true Only if A is Invertible ie. If
We are given that A^k is Diagonizable and A is Invertible
Then A is Diagonizable
. You can see the proof here [If $A$ is invertible and $A^n$ is diagonalizable, then $A$ is diagonalizable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3027664/if-a-is-invertible-and-an-is-diagonalizable-then-a-is-diagonalizable)

Here We are given that A^k = I
So A is Invertible and Identify is Always diagonizable So A is Diagonizable.

Hope This Would be Helpful for You

Comment: It's also important that we work over a field of characteristic $0$.